# Getting mysql query issue with WHERE key work. Help me to sort it out

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT c.name as "Client Name"
     , c.email as "Email"
     , c.phone as "Phone"
     , cnt.name as "Country"
     , c.street as "Street"
     , c.city_id as "City/Suburb"
     , st.name as "State"
     , c.zip_code as "Postcode"
     , "" as "Total Paid"
     , "" as "Total Owed"
     , CASE WHEN c.delete_status = 1 THEN "Not Active" ELSE "Active" END as "Status" 
  FROM customer c 
  LEFT 
  JOIN shipping_address s 
    ON c.id = s.customer_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN states st 
    ON st.id = c.state_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN countries cnt 
    ON cnt.id = c.country_id 
  WHEN c.delete_status = 0
```

Above is my query. And I am having below error message in phpmyadmin where i am not finding any issue in query.

[image: You can see error in screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change WHEN to WHERE in the query

```
SELECT c.name as "Client Name", c.email as "Email", c.phone as "Phone", cnt.name as "Country", c.street as "Street", c.city_id as "City/Suburb", st.name as "State", c.zip_code as "Postcode", "" as "Total Paid", "" as "Total Owed", ( CASE WHEN c.delete_status = 1 THEN "Not Active" ELSE "Active" END ) as "Status" FROM customer c LEFT JOIN shipping_address s ON c.id = s.customer_id LEFT JOIN states st ON st.id = c.state_id LEFT JOIN countries cnt ON cnt.id = c.country_id WHERE c.delete_status = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some issue  the error message is related  to wrong clause word 
USE where  (and not when )  for where condition

but you have also a wrong use of quote
don't use double quote for column name alias  use backtics when needed

```
  SELECT c.name as `Client Name`
  , c.email as Email
  , c.phone as Phone
  , cnt.name as Country
  , c.street as Street
  , c.city_id as `City/Suburb`
  , st.name as State
  , c.zip_code as Postcode
  , "" as `Total Paid`, "" as `Total Owed`
  , ( CASE WHEN c.delete_status = 1 THEN "Not Active" ELSE "Active" END ) as Status 
  FROM customer c 
  LEFT JOIN shipping_address s ON c.id = s.customer_id 
  LEFT JOIN states st ON st.id = c.state_id 
  LEFT JOIN countries cnt ON cnt.id = c.country_id 
  WHERE  c.delete_status = 0
```

Comment: This is a duplicate

Comment: @Strawberry  could be but this is a right answer ..  and right motivated ..clearly different respect the other one

Comment: Yes, that's all true.